# How to set textview horizontal 70 and 30 percentage in ConstraintLayout layout

Tags: android

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="14dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="14dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_bullet_point_yellow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left"
        style="@style/Tesco__Theme.Text.T3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:textColor="@color/tesco__dove_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/indicator"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="asdasdsasddsadsadsadsaddasewere ewr" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right"
        style="@style/Tesco__Theme.Text.H6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:gravity="end|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="sadsadsdsaasdasdassadsadasZ" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="indicator,tv_left,tv_right"
        app:flow_horizontalAlign="end"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="@dimen/dp_16"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="spread_inside"
        app:flow_verticalAlign="center"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the layout I am using Flow layout to align all three views horizontally I want to set tv_left 70% and tv_right 30% I have tried with app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight but its not working I don't know what ii am doing mistake please help me in this

Comment: Can you share the demo image? of what exactly you want.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/KiGFrkS.png. i want to like this but the text should visibil clear in right it should not  out of text view

Comment: Just i want set text_right 30% textleft 70% it simple i want

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. I hope I understand your question clearly.

By Using ConstraintLayout:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesett"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesett"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

By using LinearLayout weight

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_height="20dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6" />
    </LinearLayout>
```